# How to redirect excluding some slug in laravel routing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, slug

**I would like to exclude the {user} in slug route**

I want to make:

from **example.com/user/someslugs**

to exclude the {user} in slug route ***example.com/someslugs***

```
// This my Verify Controller

class VerifyController extends Controller{
    public function redirect($user, $slug){
        // Get verify
        $verify = Verify::slug($slug)->first();

        // Check if verify exists
        if (!$verify) {
            abort(404);
        }
        

        // Redirect to url
        return redirect($verify->url);
    }
}
```

Function

```
// MyFunc

if (!function_exists('verify')) {
    function verify($uri, $user){
        $model = new \App\Models\Verify;

        if (!validate_url($uri)) {
            return false;
        }

        $createVerify = function($url) use ($model){
            $slug = \Str::random(6);
            $new = $model;
            $new->url = $url;
            $new->slug = $slug;
            $new->save();

            return $slug;
        };


        $route = function($slug, $user){
            return route('verify', ['user' => $user, 'slug' => $slug]);
        };

        if (!$verify = $model->url($uri)->first()) {
            $slug = $createVerify($uri);


            return $route($slug, $user);
        }


        return $route($verify->slug, $user);
    }
}
```

Route web.php

```
// MyRouteVerify

Route::get('{user}/{slug}', 'VerifyController@redirect')->name('verify');
```

The main problem when ***I remove {user} from route*** and wrong controller is called.
How can I achieve this? to get the full URL exclude the {user}, (***example.com/someslugs***)?

Any suggestion? And I would really appreciate some good and relative answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in case you guarantee that your slug will never match your route, you can put your user route at the end of the web.php file

Example

```
// route list here
Route::get('/someroute', 'SomeController@somemethod');
  
  
// the last route in your web.php file 
Route::get('/{slug}', 'VerifyController@redirect')->name('verify');
```

I hope it's useful